# Is there a way I can make a class that accepts multiple objects in a list instead of using Children and adding one by one?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In code that I cannot access I have this.

```
var A = new ContentStack();
```

In my code I am doing the following and I would like to try and simplify so that I can add to the class `A` the items in a list instead of line by line like below

```
 A.Children.Add(new X());
 A.Children.Add(new Y());
```

Where X and Y are each Views  I created this class:

```
public class ContentStack : StackLayout
{
    
   public ContentStack()
   {
      Spacing = 0;
   }
    
   public void AddRow(View view)
   {
      this.Children.Add(view);
   }
}
```

So now I can simplify to:

```
A.AddRow(new X());
A.AddRow(new Y());
```

Is there a way that I could further simplify this with some kind of extension method or some other way so that I could have the same functionality with:

```
A.AddRows(new X(), new Y());
```

Comment: What are all those funky characters in this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void AddRows(params View[] views)
{
    foreach (var item in views)
        this.Children.Add(item);
}
```

This works:

```
A.AddRows(new X());
A.AddRows(new Y());
```

So does this:

```
A.AddRows(new X(), new Y());
```